# Is there a Batcave in Arkham City?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

In *Batman: Arkham Asylum* there was a small, but functional, Batcave.

Is there any Batcave or other Bat-place in *Arkham City*?

Comment: <Insert inappropriate comment about Catwoman here>

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No; Batman gets all his additional gear flown in.

Answer (score 7):

Actually there is a Batcave in Arkham City, although you can't access it through the story mode its just a challenge map in Riddler's Revenge which you you have to buy through DLC.

Answer (score 3):

No, Batman does not have a facility here.

> Batman will either have additional equipment flown in or he will invent additional gear based on what he finds in various villain lairs.